# Multiple Upload (PHP, Multipart, RESTAPI, POST)

Tags: php, forms, api, file-upload, upload

I am trying to write an upload script for the Odnoklassniki API. I can do the upload for a single file already but I need to do multiple uploads. The API of OK.ru can only handle one upload at once so I need to do a loop in PHP to at first select all files, getting the Upload ID and link, make the request to grant all permissions.

I need to write a script which at first grab all video with a simple form, submits them to a PHP with will get the name and will arrange them in an array, then requests a upload link + the id, will upload them, grant the permissions and insert them into a database and this in a loop.

What I can do:
- Granting permission is easy (video.update will handle it)
- Inserting them into the database after the whole process
- Getting the names of the file is easy too:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
$name       = $file['name'];
//looping to get the names
}
```

- Requesting the upload url

This is what I already have:

upload.html:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
<input type="file" name="v1[]"  accept="video/\*" multiple/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

process.php:

same as above (getting the name)
plus this here:

```
$videoname = "$name" . ".mkv";

$video = OdnoklassnikiSDK::makeRequest("video.getUploadUrl", array("file_name" =>"$videoname","file_size" => "0"));
$json = json_encode($video);
$upload = $video["upload_url"]; 
$id = $video["video_id"]; 
echo"<form method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"$upload\">
<input type=\"file\" name=\"v1[]\"  accept=\"video/\*\" multiple/>
<input type=\"submit\" />
</form>";
$ul = OdnoklassnikiSDK::makeRequest("video.update", array("vid" => "$id","title" => "$name"));
```

As you see, this is for uploading only one file because of the form in the "process.php". So how can I upload multiple files not to an folder like many scripts are doing it but rather to the upload url like this one: (censored)

http://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?id=18995350025&appId=XXXXXX&expires=1420769710535&userId=XXXXXXX&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXa844e69d50ecf71f9554aae&clientType=4

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why not put your block of code into a loop?

Comment: Do you mean the process.php? Because i don´t know how to make a fileupload to the upload url, all tutorials are just for local uploads in folders